# SOLR - sunspot_rails/sunspot_solr 2.1 - NO JSP support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsp, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm currently using the master branch of the [sunspot_rails/sunspot_solr gem](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) and when I run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run` the following error occurs:

```
2013-12-22 14:46:48.884:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
```

**How do I go about rectifying this error and thereby enabling JSP support for my Rails SOLR environment?**

Furthermore my `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex` command is causing the below errors on each index attempt:

```
14:48:06
SEVERE
SolrCore
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
14:48:06
SEVERE
SolrDispatchFilter
null:java.lang.NullPointerException
null:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm assuming that the initial JSP support error is causing my indexing to fail.

Any help in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching SOLR in favour of Elasticsearch. I found the setup for SOLR was too much of a hassle, for both development and production, and it had very limited configuration options.

You can download and install the Elasticsearch service at their official site: http://www.elasticsearch.org.

In order to use the search service with Rails, just include the gem in your application gemfile:

`gem 'searchkick'`

You can also find more information on how to configure your instance on their Github wiki: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/README.md

Hope this proves helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when upgrading to sunspot_solr 2.2. Here's how I solved the issue:

1. `bundle install`
2. Delete `/solr` directory completely since solr/config/solrconfig.xml, solr/data, and other files are outdated.
3. `bundle exec rails generate sunspot_rails:install`
4. `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run` # this will recreate your `/solr` directory with its config and other files
5. `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex`